# Pass the variable value to curl JSON

Tags: variable, curl, json, variable-substitution

I am trying to create a JIRA ticket using curl POST method, but the variable substitution is not happening properly in `TODAY_DATE` variable. If i remove that it is working fine. ANy hint on how this can be solved?

Below is my code where only `TODAY_DATE` substition isnt working and failing with below error

```
#!/bin/bash
JIRA_CREDS="XXX:YYY"
JIRA_PROJECT="OPS"
JIRA_URL="http://jira/jira/rest/api/2/issue/"
JIRA_CONTENT_TYPE="Content-Type: application/json"
DATE_1=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f1`
DATE_2=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f2`
DATE_3=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f3 | cut -d" " -f2`
TODAY_DATE=`echo "${DATE_1}:${DATE_2} ${DATE_3}"`
 curl -D- -u "$JIRA_CREDS" -X POST --data '{
 "fields": {
 "project":
 {
 "key": "'$JIRA_PROJECT'"
 },
 "summary": "Security patch update",
 "description": "The instances need to be updated via yum.",
 "customfield_13339": { "value": "Bamboo" },
 "customfield_13338": { "value": "Approved" } ,
 "customfield_13337": [{ "value": "Team" }],
 "customfield_13331": [{ "value": "SITTR" }],
 "customfield_13334": { "value": "'$TODAY_DATE'" },
 "issuetype": {
 "name": "Tech Task"
 }
 }
 }' -H "$JIRA_CONTENT_TYPE" "$JIRA_URL"

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.11: Invalid argument
curl: (23) Failed writing header
```

Comment: Your json object is an escaping nightmare.  Try storing it in a variable using a here doc or use something like jo to create it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore whatever quoting issues you may have and rewrite your script with the JSON construction tool `jo`.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

jira_creds='XXX:YYY'
jira_project='OPS'
jira_url='http://jira/jira/rest/api/2/issue/'
jira_content_type='Content-Type: application/json'

now=$( date +'%d/%b/%y %l:%M %p' )

json_data=$( jo -d . \
        fields.project.key="$jira_project" \
        fields.summary='Security patch update' \
        fields.description='The instances need to be updated via yum.' \
        fields.customfield_13339.value='Bamboo' \
        fields.customfield_13338.value='Approved' \
        fields.customfield_13337="$( jo -a "$( jo value='Team' )" )" \
        fields.customfield_13331="$( jo -a "$( jo value='SITTR' )" )" \
        fields.customfield_13334.value="$now" \
        fields.issuetype.name='Tech Task'
)

curl \
        -u "$jira_creds" \
        -X POST --data "$json_data" \
        -H "$jira_content_type" \
        "$jira_url"
```

The value of `$json_data` would be a properly formatted JSON document where all included variable data has been JSON-encoded if needed.  Pretty-printed, it may look something like

```json
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "OPS"
    },
    "summary": "Security patch update",
    "description": "The instances need to be updated via yum.",
    "customfield_13339": {
      "value": "Bamboo"
    },
    "customfield_13338": {
      "value": "Approved"
    },
    "customfield_13337": [
      {
        "value": "Team"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_13331": [
      {
        "value": "SITTR"
      }
    ],
    "customfield_13334": {
      "value": "05/May/21 11:32 PM"
    },
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Tech Task"
    }
  }
}
```

---

And alternative way to create the JSON payload data is to start with a static YAML document (which is easy to write) and then insert the variable data into it with `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
json_data=$( yq \
        --arg proj "$jira_project" \
        '.fields.project.key |= $proj |
         .fields.customfield_13334.value |=
                (now|strflocaltime("%d/%b/%y %l:%M %p"))' <<'END_YAML'
fields:
  summary: Security patch update
  description: The instances need to be updated via yum.
  customfield_13339:
    value: Bamboo
  customfield_13338:
    value: Approved
  customfield_13337:
    - value: Team
  customfield_13331:
    - value: SITTR
  issuetype:
    name: Tech Task
END_YAML
)
```

Note that we let `yq` compute the timestamp here, so the shell variable `$now` is no longer needed in the script.

Comment: When I do that `jo` thing I am getting the following error `"errors":{"customfield_13334":"Operation value must be a string"}}`

Comment: @sabarishjackson What is the value of `$json_data` if you use `echo "$json_data"` before calling `curl`?

Comment: This is what i get when i run with echo ${json_data}  `"fields":{"project":{"key":"OPS"},"summary":"Security patch update","description":"The instances need to be updated via yum.","customfield_13339":{"value":"Bamboo"},"customfield_13338":{"value":"Approved"},"customfield_13337":[{"value":"Team"}],"customfield_13331":[{"value":"SITTR"}],"customfield_13334":{"value":"10/May/21 9:52 PM"},"issuetype":{"name":"Tech Task"}}}
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_13334":"Operation value must be a string"}}`

Answer (score 0):

In your script, a couple of variable expansions are unquoted:

```
 "key": "'$JIRA_PROJECT'"
```

and

```
 "customfield_13334": { "value": "'$TODAY_DATE'" },
```

Those two lines should be, respectively:

```
"key": "'"$JIRA_PROJECT"'"
```

and

```
"customfield_13334": { "value": "'"$TODAY_DATE"'" },
```

As an aside, you may also write `TODAY_DATE="${DATE_1}:${DATE_2} ${DATE_3}"`, saving an unneeded command substitution/`echo`. Or, better, `TODAY_DATE=$(date +"%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p")`, removing the need for the `DATE_n` variables.

The expansion of `$TODAY_DATE` includes space characters:

```bsh
$ DATE_1=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f1`
$ DATE_2=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f2`
$ DATE_3=`date +"%d/%b/%y %r" | cut -d":" -f3 | cut -d" " -f2`
$ TODAY_DATE=`echo "${DATE_1}:${DATE_2} ${DATE_3}"`
$ printf '%s\n' "$TODAY_DATE"
05/May/21 10:06 PM
```

Most likely this means that the argument to the `--data` option in your script is ending with the first word of `TODAY_DATE`'s value. The following word (`10:06` in this case) is being parsed by `curl` as the first non-option argument an hence taken as the URL to connect to (I am not able to reproduce the exact error you show, though).

See also: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/315749)

Comment: If i do this i am getting a below error `{"customfield_13334":"Operation value must be a string"}` That is actually Custom field for date column and it is being displayed in 05/May/21 10:06 PM format

Comment: @sabarishjackson Maybe it is meant to be `"customfield_13334": "'"$TODAY_DATE"'",`? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with JIRA tickets.